# Neovim: Moving selected text to another file selected by fzf

Tags: vim, neovim, fzf, vim-fzf

I find myself selecting text from a vim buffer and appending it to another file. I currently do that by:

- select the text with Shift + V
- in commend mode, execute: w >> my_file

This requires that I write the exact filepath to my_file. Instead, I would like to use fzf.vim to fuzzy find the file I am writing into. What is the best way to do this?

I tried the following, but it just append bunch of garbage instead of selected text.

`call fzf#run({'sink': 'w>>'})`

Comment: You know Vim has built-in filename completion, right?

Comment: if you mean tab completion, I have been using that but it's not optimal. The new files I need to copy my text into are nested into directory and I need to remember the path of the file. I am trying to simplify this with fuzzy finder.

Comment: Hmm. Doing `:w >> **my<Tab>` then a couple of `<Tab>`s may not be as *refined* as the fuzzy magic of fzf, but it sure is pretty optimal. Making it a mapping would be even more optimal.

Comment: Hitting <Tab> works only when you know when the file is located. For example: I have 10 directories under my Documents folder. Each one of them has 2-3 directories which contains documents. When I need to copy text into file.txt, I need to know it's path [dirA/dirB/file.txt]. <Tab>ing can help me write this path without typing it but it can't help me if I don't already know that file.txt lives in dirA/dirB (unless I am missing something here).

Comment: Yes, you are a) thinking about the command I suggested instead of trying it and b) you are missing the `**`.